# Why is there no \ProvideCommandCopy?

Tags: macros, latex3, robust-commands

When we look at `xparse` package documentation there are four related commands

```
\NewDocumentCommand
\RenewDocumentCommand
\ProvideDocumentCommand
\DeclareDocumentCommand
```

Similarly there are four commands for environments. When I've learned about `\NewCommandCopy` I've expected a similar four commands will be available. But looking at LaTeX source I've only found that

```
\NewCommandCopy
\RenewCommandCopy
\DeclareCommandCopy
```

are defined.

Is there a technical reason why `\ProvideCommandCopy` was not defined?

EDIT: Example usecase

In the answer by [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643102/269072) it is claimed that there is no usecase for such command.

Let's consider that we want to provide a black-and-white switch for the document and we want to use `\IfBooleanTF` from `xparse` because we are familiar with it. We know that it exports values `\BooleanFalse` and `\BooleanTrue` so we may write for example

```
\NewCommandCopy\blackandwhite\BooleanFalse

\IfBooleanTF{\blackandwhite}{...}{...}
```

Let's say we want to pass it when compiling document such as `pdflatex '\NewCommandCopy\blackandwhite\BooleanTrue\input{document.tex}'`. This will obviously cause errors because `\blackandwhite` is already defined. If there was `\ProvideCommandCopy` we could use it to define the default value of `\blackandwhite` switch in case user does not provide it. Currently we are forced to always define it explicitly.

Obviously there are other ways to make the black-and-white switch work as intended, but I think this is a valid usecase of `ProvideCommandCopy`.

Comment: In your `\blackandwhite` use case, `\(new|provide)command\blackandwhite{\BooleanTrue}` works. I think `\NewCommandCopy` and friends are mostly for redefining, not aliasing things.

Comment: I get
`! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \??? ! LaTeX cmd Error: Invalid argument {\blackandwhite } to \IfBooleanTF{\blackandwhite}{a}{b}` when trying to use `\(new|provide)command`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `\newcommand` and `\providecommand`. The point is to wrap `\BooleanTrue` in a macro, not copy it.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ This is what I used: `\newcommand{\blackandwhite}{\BooleanTrue}`. I got the error mentioned in the previous comment when trying to use `\IfBooleanTF{\blackandwhite}{a}{b}`.

Comment: Hmm `\IfBooleanTF` is not as flexible as I think. `\expandafter\IfBooleanTF\blackandwhite{a}{b}` or use other ways like `\csname xxx\endcsname` and `\ifdefined\xxx <true>\else<false>\fi`.

Comment: Your proposals to solve the given problem are of course correct, but the question was about use-case of `ProvideCommandCopy` which I still believe is a valid one.

Comment: Another range of use-cases could be making another command's definition the default in case the command to be defined is not already defined.

Comment: I don't understand why there are many new commands for declaring control sequences. We have `\def`, `\edef`, `\let` and `\gdef`, `\xdef`, `\mathchardef`, `\chardef` etc. No more is needed.

Comment: @wipet For example `\NewCommandCopy` works properly with robust commands in contrast to `\let`. It also checks whether the command isn't already defined, which helps prevent accidental overwrites.

Comment: @nim We have `\protected\def`, i.e. we need not something like "robust commands". The `\let` command copies the `\protected` feature of the macro. And if we need to ask if the control sequence is defined, we can do `\ifx\macro\undefined`.

Comment: @wipet I'm not knowledgeable enough to say whether `\protected\def` covers all edge cases, but your point about `\ifx\macro\undefined` is weird to me. I was writing about *accidental* overwrites. If you explicitly cover that case then it's not accidental. If you propose putting that before every def then maybe we could define a macro to save on typing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a `\ProvideCommandCopy` because it isn't useful (and may be harmful even), so the decision was to not implement it.  There is a note in the implementation (`texdoc source2e`, section **Copying robust commands** in `ltdefns.dtx`):

> [image: A \ProvideCommandCopy isn’t defined because it’s not reasonably useful. \provide... commands mean “define this if there’s no other definition”, but copying a command (usually) implies that the command being copied is defined, so \ProvideCommandCopy doesn’t make a lot of sense. But more importantly, the most common use case of copying a command is to redefine it later, while preserving the old definition, as in: \ProvideComandCopy \A \B \renewcommand \B { ... \A ... } then, if \A is already defined the first line is skipped, an in this case \B won’t work as expected.]

Comment: I do not understand the provided reasoning. While it is true that the command being copied *from* usually exists, the command copied *to* usually doesn't. That's why `\RenewCommandCopy` exists. It doesn't redefine the original command but the new copy.

Comment: @nim: the second argument is the more important one: typically you want to use the copy to redefine the original command \B or to keep \B "alive" for other uses, but with \ProvideCommandCopy you have no idea what the content of \A actually is and anyone could destroy your code simply by defining `\A`.

Comment: Phelype, there is a typo in the text ;-) Comand instead of Command.

Comment: @nim "provide" is usually a kind of "backup definition" in case there is no other, but when you are copying a command (#2), it makes no sense to copy if you don't know whether/how it's defined.  The definition of the copied-to command would be unpredictable.  Should you want to provide a reasonable use-case for `\ProvideCommandCopy`, we could ponder

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oops, I'll fix. Thanks.  I am good at wtiring :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you should learn from hte older mbers of th latx projct, who nver make typos

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `teh older mbers`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've edited the question with a usecase example.

Answer (score 5):

I assume most just use the typical commands for writing documents. I think only a small percentage of the user base programs and defines rather sophisticated things at all in TeX/LaTeX.

I think the reasoning for not providing `\ProvideCommandCopy` in the LaTeX 2ε-kernel is: `\ProvideCommandCopy` would be a possible pitfall. Besides this `\ProvideCommandCopy` would be seldom needed. Thus in most scenarios having it in the kernel would imply having something in the kernel that is not used and thus in most scenarios is just ballast. Scenarios where `\ProvideCommandCopy` might be needed are at an advanced level where the user should be capable of defining it her-/himself. ;-)

I wrote: "I **think** the reasoning ... is ...". So it is a guess. Neither am I a member of the LaTeX development team, nor do I have much insight, so I can't really speak for that team and justify team decisions.

I'm speculating on this reasoning because I heard it before with similar questions I asked in the past.

*But to me it doesn't matter, because for what I need frequently and therefore define frequently, I have my own macro package and extraction routines that—in case of code sharing—extract only those of my own definitions that are really needed. Thus, creating a new template file that contains only those of my own definitions that are needed in the specific scenario is done with one mouse click. ;-)*

---

Instead of arguing with people who for some reason don't want to see that I need what I need, if I felt I needed a `\ProvideCommandCopy` command, I would simply define it myself.

This is done in the example below.

---

`\DeclareCommandCopy` defines the command to be defined in any case, which does not exclude that it is redefined in the process. If redefining takes place, this is done silently, i.e., **no** error-message or the like is raised.

`\RenewCommandCopy` defines the command to be defined in any case, which does not exclude that it is redefined in the process. If it is not already defined, **an** error message is raised beforehand.

`\NewCommandCopy` defines the command to be defined if it is not defined. If it is already defined, **an** error message is raised and the command is not redefined.

`\ProvideCommandCopy` defines the command to be defined if it is not defined. If it is already defined, **no** error message is raised and the command is not redefined.

The  difference between `\RenewCommandCopy`/`\DeclareCommandCopy` and `\NewCommandCopy`/`\ProvideCommandCopy` is that the further redefine the command to define if it is already defined, while the latter don't redefine it if it is already defined.

The  difference between `\NewCommandCopy`/`\RenewCommandCopy` and `\ProvideCommandCopy`/`\DeclareCommandCopy` is that the further raise an error-message if the command to be defined is (not) already defined, while the latter don't raise an error-message.

**All(!!!) these `\...CommandCopy`-commands do not check whether the command to be copied is defined.**

With all these `\...CommandCopy`-commands the (re)definition is limited to the local scope where the respective `\...CommandCopy`-command is executed.

With all these `\...CommandCopy`-commands checking whether the command to be defined is already defined is limited to the local scope where the respective `\...CommandCopy`-command is executed.

```latex
\makeatletter
\providecommand*\ProvideCommandCopy{%
  \declare@commandcopy{\@firstofone}{\@firstoftwo{}}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\CommandToCopy{Copy}
\newcommand\CommandBToCopy{CopyB}
\newcommand\CommandCToCopy{CopyC}
\newcommand\CommandDToCopy{CopyD}

\begingroup

\NewCommandCopy\Copy\CommandToCopy
\message{You should get "\long macro:->Copy" and you get "\meaning\Copy"}

\RenewCommandCopy\Copy\CommandBToCopy
\message{You should get "\long macro:->CopyB" and you get "\meaning\Copy"}

\DeclareCommandCopy\Copy\CommandCToCopy
\message{You should get "\long macro:->CopyC" and you get "\meaning\Copy"}

% \Copy in the current scope is already defined equal to \ComandCToCopy, thus
% \ProvideCommandCopy does not redefine \Copy:

\ProvideCommandCopy\Copy\CommandDToCopy
\message{You should get "\long macro:->CopyC" and you get "\meaning\Copy"}

\endgroup

% Now \Copy is undefined
% \Copy is not defined in the current scope, thus \ProvideCommandCopy within
% the current scope makes \Copy equal to \CommandDToCopy:

\ProvideCommandCopy\Copy\CommandDToCopy
\message{You should get "\long macro:->CopyD" and you get "\meaning\Copy"}

\stop
```

Console output:

```
latex-dev test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
You should get "\long macro:->Copy" and you get "\long macro:->Copy"
You should get "\long macro:->CopyB" and you get "\long macro:->CopyB"
You should get "\long macro:->CopyC" and you get "\long macro:->CopyC"
You should get "\long macro:->CopyC" and you get "\long macro:->CopyC"
You should get "\long macro:->CopyD" and you get "\long macro:->CopyD" )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Actually I don't see a proper reasoning for not having `\ProvideCommandCopy`.
*(Note that "having `\ProvideCommandCopy`" is not the same as "including `\ProvideCommandCopy` into the kernel". One can, e.g., have a command/macro/function by providing its definition in the preamble or via some home-brewed macro-package.)*

Use-cases could include scenarios where `\ProvideCommandCopy` is used for making another command's definition the default in case the command to be defined is not already defined.

In my humble opinion `\ProvideCommandCopy` is not more harmful than the other `\...CommandCopy` commands as long as its usage goes along with sufficient care.

If you want to copy a command for redefining it later, while preserving the old definition, you—be it defined or not—**in any case do not use `\ProvideCommandCopy` for the purpose of storing the old definition**:

If `\ProvideCommandCopy` is not defined you simply can't use it for this purpose.

If `\ProvideCommandCopy` is defined you don't use it for this purpose because `\ProvideCommandCopy` is the only one of these commands which allows the scenario of **silently not storing** the old definition. (With `\NewCommandCopy` the not-storing is not silent but you get an error-message if storing goes along with overriding something that already exists. Both with `\RenewCommandCopy` and with `\DeclareCommandCopy` storing takes place in any case while only the further implies raising an error-message if storing goes along with not overriding but defining anew the macro that is to hold the stored definition.)

I don't think the argument of `\ProvideCopyCommand` not making much sense due to usually the command to be copied being already defined, is very convincing: The command to be copied is not the command to be defined. The LaTeX-kernel's `\providecommand`, and thus probably also a (hypothetical) command `\ProvideCopyCommand`,  does not check whether the command to be copied is already  defined, but does check whether the command to be defined is already defined.

Loosely based on Forrest Gump: And that's all I  have to say about that. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding the "defining it myself" comment, I obviously agree, but this question was more about the reasoning for its omission in the kernel.

Comment: While I agree that this command would be rarely used I don't think that it's a good reason for omission. Even advanced users can make mistakes while defining something, and it simply wastes time. Could you elaborate why it's a ballast? The example mentioned in the `source2e` as a pitfall seems rather unconvincing because this code would behave just as I, and everybody who is familiar with `Provide...` semantics, expected. Also the document clearly states that the command doesn't make sense, while I think your answer demonstrates that it has perfectly reasonable semantics.

Comment: @nim If you think `\ProvideCommandCopy` should be provided (no pun intended), the most likely way to get that would be to open an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm far from pressing inclusion of this into the kernel. For the following reasons: 1) S/he who wants to have `\ProvideCommandCopy` is free to define it her-/himself. In my answer I showed how to do so. So not having it in the kernel seems not like massive thwarting of features. 2) I am much less able than the LaTeX development team to judge which things it is reasonable to include them into the kernel and thus to push them to the broad user community, and which things it is not reasonable to do because far too few people would use them (correctly).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't really care that much, I just wanted to know the reasoning. I'll accept your answer since it points to official justification by the LaTeX team and it's not your fault that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nim I wrote the code for `\NewCommandCopy` and the documentation, so if you want someone to blame, here I am :) And the reasoning was that it would cause more harm than good, and it would not be terribly useful (as far as I could see).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik In the documentation there is the sentence "but copying a command (usually) implies that the command being copied is defined" and in your comment you wrote "it makes no sense to copy if you don't know whether/how it's defined". These don't make sense to me. If I write `\ProvideCommandCopy\A\B` I know whether `\B` exist and how it's defined. I don't know whether `\A` exists and I'm fine with it being a copy if it doesn't. Your counterpoint that "you have no idea what the content of \A actually is" applies equally to every `\Provide...` command, so why are those not harmful?